# weird one: how do i modify a light switch wiring so it stays on regardless on if it's flipped up or down?

Tags: switch, light

I know it's weird. But I want the light ON regardless if the switch is flipped up or down. How can I do this? which wires do I cross? Thank You

Comment: If you succeed, where there still be a light switch that works and turns on a light in the room? Is this about switched receptacles that you want unswitched?

Comment: There maybe building and electrical code issues depending on what the area the light serves. Beyond that there are various switch configurations (dimmers and Occ sensors with and w/o neutrals, whites used as hots, switches with wire leads) so a short concise answer can be misleading without seeing the back of the switch.

Comment: Can you post a photo of the inside of the box please?  Is there a reason you are wanting to leave the switch there instead of inserting a blank filler in its place?

Comment: Your post needs more information if you actually want to modify the wiring. I suggest a simple [locking tab](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/61bzlpb-42L._AC_SL1500_.jpg).

Comment: _Why_ the OP wants this could use some clarity, but the question itself is pretty clear. Maybe if we find out more about the situation, better solutions could be offered.

Answer (score 3):

First, this is probably a bad idea.  Connecting the wires and then just reinstalling a non-working switch is not good practice and confusing to the next person.

A standard light switch has two wires going to it.  When the switch is on, those two wires are internally connected, and when off, they are disconnected.  So, to make it "always on", you just need to connect those two wires together.  That's a basic description, and again, probably isn't the right solution to your problem.

One simple thing you can do is put a guard over the switch so its not accidentally flipped.

[image: Light switch guard]

[Example listing on Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B078PPG44X), you can probably buy locally.

This cover leaves the switch intact, doesn't violate any codes, but lets the switch remain always on.  I know a lot about electrical wiring, and this is what I used when I installed a wireless remote on a ceiling fan and wanted the switch to be always on.

Comment: I don't know if you have an equivalent your side of the Atlantic, but here we have [switches meant for emergency lights](https://www.toolstation.com/click-mode-key-switch/p81000) that can only be operated with a (universal) key. Not all are labelled for emergency lighting.  I keep meaning to fit one where I have a wireless remote and the light is a long way from the switch

Comment: @ChrisH, Yea, in the US, we have a keyed light switch that looks [like this](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Leviton-15-20-Amp-Single-Pole-Industrial-Locking-Toggle-Switch-Brown-R50-01221-0DL/202034986).  I've only ever seen them used in places like schools and hospitals for the common area lighting that almost never needs to turn off.  Building maintenance staff would carry a key...

Comment: The key looks very similar.  I've used them (years ago) as an anti-tamper switch in a youth club where it didn't make sense to reroute the wiring and  get the switches out of the way of the kids.

Comment: Man, I _found_ one of the little tamper-resistant-switch keys. Looked a little like a fork. Carried it on my key ring for _years_. I think I used it twice. :( It was _super_ handy to have those 2 times I needed it! Of relevance to the answer, this switch cover allows the power to be turned off with _intentional effort_, as opposed to mindlessly flipping the switch when leaving the room.

Comment: It seems that "keyed light switch" website just shows *Access denied* to visitors from Europe; I had to use Google Cache to dig out [the product image](https://images.thdstatic.com/productImages/48804e23-cb9d-4f73-bb04-234c45d8521f/svn/ivory-leviton-light-switches-r50-01221-0dl-64_600.jpg).

Comment: Thanks @user1686,  I would have posted the image if it was in the answer body - got lazy in the comments.